# Углы Эйлера в юнити

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Что это за углы, для чего нужны в юнити?  Кратко объясните пожалуйста.

Зачем их использовать , если есть `transform.Rotate`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Transform.Rotate` поворачивает `transform` объекта и делает это моментально, меняя объект.

`Quaternion.Euler` создаёт квартернион, который хранит информацию только об ориентации/повороте в пространстве. Он не применяет операции поворота к объекту моментально.

Если вам нужна информация только о повороте: вы хотите её закешировать, сравнивать с другими, комбинировать их т.п - тогда лучше использовать `Quaternion.Euler`, чтобы не спамить кучу временных объектов.